# Compute outliers using Zscore

Tags: pandas

I want to save the outliers using the zcore method in my dataframe df1. Is what im doing correct?

**Code**

```
df1= df[~(np.abs(df.col1-df.col1.mean()) <= (3*df.col1.std()))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `pandas.eval` and `pandas.assign` for better readability:

```
import pandas as pd

df['outlier'] = df.assign(z_score = lambda x: (x.col1 - x.col1.mean())/x.col1.std()
              ).eval('z_score > 3')
```

Outliers are datapoints with z-score **higher** than threshold so if you want `outlier` column to say `True` for outlier use `>` instead of `<=`.